# How to svn unversion a file/folder on linux server (using command line only)

Tags: svn

I have a file on linux server which i want to unversion using linux command line, so that my local machine/laptop wouldn't pick it up

I want the file to reside only on the server and not sync to local machine.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `svn rm --keep-local <the_file>`.

From http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.delete.html:

> Use the --keep-local option to override the default svn delete behavior of also removing the target file that was scheduled for versioned deletion. This is helpful when you realize that you've accidentally committed the addition of a file that you need to keep around in your working copy, but which shouldn't have been added to version control.